# Use a HashSet as a constant

Tags: java, constants, hashset

I have a method which is used for converting a map of objects into human readable key-value pairs. To do this I need some characters such as quotes, spaces and backslash that by default will be interpreted as control characters and need escaping if used in the key or value. As there will not be any duplicates and I need a fast lookup I have assumed that a set would be the best option but as (to my knowelege) you cannot lock a set it may be accidentally changed.

Is it at good idea to have a HashSet as a constant, is there a way to make it immutable, is it a good idea to follow the constant naming convention with it (UPPER_CASE) and how would you place initial values in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Collections.unmodifiableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29), to make your set immutable once created. Use set if you don't want duplicate elements within your object collections. Optionally the element within myset are immutable as well so nobody could modify the state of either set nor elements within the set.

```
Set<String> elementSet = new HashSet<String>();
elementSet.add("abc");//to populate
elementSet.add("pqr");
Collections.unmodifiableSet(elementSet);
```

Comment: Should I name the constant as I would with a constant int/string with UPPER_CASE? Is using a static block a good idea to populate it?

Comment: Yes you are right in following code covention http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html. Yes you could initialize it in static block if you are planning to use this set field as static.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use the all-uppercase convention for the field name.

You can initialize the variable in a single statement, without a static initialization block:

```
private static final Set<Character> SPECIAL_CHARACTERS =
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('"', '\'', ' ', '\\')));
```